# How to use UI.body.events in Meteor Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to attach a couple scroll events to the new UI.body.events. I want to have the scroll events fired at all times on all routes but only be assigned once, so I figured this would be the right place to assign them.

Taken from: 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#uibody-is-now-a-template-corresponding-to-the-entire-body-element

```
UI.body.events({
  'click': function () {
    alert("clicked somewhere on the page");
  }
});
```

This should be obvious probably, but my question is where do I insert this bit of code in my app? You would think anywhere, but I tried it in main.js, as its own UI.js file in my client/helpers/ folder, inside a `rendered` template callback, but it seems it never fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, interesting.  `UI.body.events` is [supposedly not implemented](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2024) yet, so I'm surprised it works for Keith Nicholas.  Apparently, [it's coming in version 0.8.1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-talk/UI.body%2420events/meteor-talk/iuHfjk7zgSk/KOHZaklmJN8J), but you just have to use jQuery to bind events to `document.body` for the time being.

Comment: thanks. I think this is related to IronRouter then. will use `document.body` for now

Comment: works ok for me :)  but then, I am using the windows version, maybe something got snuck in on that one

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, I just copy pasted it into a js file in my client folder I'm currently working on and it instantly started working.